# how to recover virtual machines back in case of virtual machine failure

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu-10.04, kvm-virtualization

I am having a virtualization setup via KVM on a Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit  server.

A recent dbus update cause a crash of my Host OS.It was a post install script of dbus which ultimately brought everything down.

Now I have to basically format the host OS.My cause of concern are the virtual machines which were running on it when the environment was stable.Which were in separate LVM partitions.

Some thing like

```
/dev/virtualization/vm1
/dev/virtualization/vm2
/dev/virtualization/vm3
/dev/virtualization/vm4
```

If some one has experienced recovery of this sort in past let me know what did they do to get things back.
All my Virtual Machines were on separate partition and in same VolumeGroup this volume group was on Host OS.
Will formatting of HOST os clear the Virtual Machines also in my situation or just be re installing the host and importing the Virtual Machines via a tool such as virt-manager I will be able to get them back.Before I begin formatting HOST os I need suggestion from serverfault experts.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the VM images are on a separate VG, all you need to do is avoid formatting it when reinstalling - go for manual partitioning and make sure the "virtualization" VG is not touched

What you need to preserve is the VM configs, because besides the image there's all the setup data - usually in /etc/libvirt/qemu/guestname.xml

Comment: Thanks this had really worked.How ever I had also done 
run: virsh define /path/to/vm.xml
for better safety and I was able to get my environment back.

Comment: yup, virsh also has a "dump" verb that can do the same iirc